# How to Concatenate multiples variables with different size using Matlab ?

Tags: matlab, loops, concatenation

I have a multiple variables of different size : `A1xB1 , A2xB2, A3xB3, ...`

I would like to put them all in one VOLUME something like `AxBxC`.

Let's suppose `I` can take values of size `AixBi`.

I found that the following loop :

```
for ... 
     Volume = cat(3,Volume,I)
endfor
```

can concatenate `I` and produce VOLUME in **case `I` are of the same size**.

But What can I do when `I` can take different sizes ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense; what is the relationship between `AxB` and `A1xB1`, `A2xB2`, etc.?

Comment: As @OliverCharlesworth noted, you can only concatenate arrays of the same size, since the result has to have a well-defined size of `n1 x n2 x n3`. You can either pad your original variables with zeros to the largest dimensions appearing, *or* you can use a cell array, with each element a 2d array of various sizes.

Comment: okey, to make it more clear, suppose A1=A2=A etc and B1=B2=B I can have a volume containing C elements of size AxB

Comment: @AndrasDeak thank you , that's what I was looking for.. I will try to use Cell Arrays. Padding not good for my case.

Comment: @AndrasDeak you can transform your comment to answer please :)

Comment: Thank you:) I edited my original answer, I realized that using `deal` is unnecessary. However, it would have its uses if you wanted to reverse the concatenation, so I thought I'd let you know about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `cat` to concatenate arrays *of the same size*, since the resulting array has to be a proper array of size `n1 x n2 x n3`. Since in comments you told us that padding your variables is not an option, you have to use a cell array, each element of which will correspond to one of your matrices.

You can use a loop,

```
C = cell(1,nmats); %nmats number of arrays to concatenate
for n=1:nmats
   C{n} = ...; %your n-th array goes here
end
```

Or for a pre-defined *small* number of arrays you can also call

```
%C = cell(1,nmats);
%[C{:}] = deal(arr_1,arr_2,...*add variables here*...,arr_nmats);
C = {arr_1,arr_2,...*add variables here*...,arr_nmats};
```

I commented out my original version, which works, but is needlessly complicated. However, the approach of `deal` would be useful *for reversing* your concatenation:

```
[arr_1,arr_2,...*add variables here*...,arr_nmats] = deal(C{:});
```

to the same effect.